# Why doesn't function generator documentation ever mention the maximum output current?

Tags: power, impedance, output

The output impedance mentioned, but how does this translate to maximum current? What happens if you short circuit the output of a function generator?

Let's take the XR-2206 for example.

The datasheet states an output impedance only for triangle wave of 600 ohms and nothing for the other wave forms.

Why is this 'never' important?

Comment: please post a link to the datasheet that you are referring to

Comment: The XR-2206 is a chip to implement a part of a device called function generator, so there should be some circuitry between a chip and output connector to do some buffering and amplification.

Comment: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/80496/EXAR/XR2206.html

Comment: This is about understanding the more general idea, really, not specifically about this one chip

Comment: What more general? I have a Siglent SDG1302 and it has all the specification, it even self diminishes the amplitude setting at higher frequencies. So really don't understand your question, the IC XR-2206 itself has to be connected to a buffer.

Comment: Because you're not expected to connect something to it with a lower input impedance than specified.

Comment: there is no minimal input impedance of something to be connected specified either, so...

Comment: The func generator will have enough drive capability for a 50ohm cable load at the max voltage and frequency for the square or pulse output per specs for wave shape. Beyond that, if it doesn't say, expect that you might need an amplifier.

Comment: Output it is protected by an internal resistor, after the out amplifier

Comment: Good function generators typically have a fuse. A function generator gives variable shape, frequency, amplitude, offset and duty cycle at limited power.  That is the compromise because it's an some flavor of op-amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is output impedance mentioned, but how does this translate to max. current?

I = V/R, so assuming you know the voltage you can calculate the current.

> Why is this 'never' important?

If you're going to be driving a load then presumably you would use a driver IC or amplifier suitable for that load, making the current limit irrelevant.

Comment: This is not very clear. What is the 'R' in this example? The load or the output resistance of the signal generator?